# Is $\mathbb{C}P^{\infty}$, the infinite complex projective space simply connected?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Is $\mathbb{C}P^{\infty}$ simply connected?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. The 2-skeleton is, and by cellular approximation thus the whole space is.